# Using EC2 instance to send large amount of emails using SES API (BOTO - Python)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, amazon-ses

Currently I have a Python script that sends a large amount of emails and I throttle the emails by using threads then sleeping the main thread after x number of times to comply with Amazon Max Rate restrictions.

I am using this script: [GitHub](https://github.com/jvillacortam/SES_mailer/blob/master/emailer.py) as a benchmark tool for my EC2 instance and my personal computer.

My EC2 is in the same region as the SES end point; taking that into consideration the script should be able to finish each batch of emails faster but in reality it is considerably slower.

EC2 takes an average of 0.2 to 0.3 seconds while locally it takes less than 0.1. My concern is that we want to be able to send up to 70 emails per second and based on this readings we will not be able to.

AMAZON INSTANCE:

- Type: m3.medium
- Zone: us-east-1c

Answer (score 0):

An `m3.medium` is basically a single core PC with about 4GB of memory.  That's probably significantly less powerful than your personal computer.  If you want better performance, I would try using a more powerful instance such as an `m3.large`.